sumar la diferencia de las horas extras en vba de excel
tengo una macro que me suma pero solo con números, además quiero poner condiciones y no me resulta nada. por ejemplo la macro debería recorrer un rango de celdas y cuando pase por cada celda debería entrar la siguiente condición "si la celda activa es menor a 20:00 restar (20:00 - celda activa) y acumular la suma en una celda de mi elección y si la celda no la cumple sumar si la celda es mayor o igual a "06:11" si es mayor sumar y si no seguir a la siguiente celda la suma se acumula en una celda pre seleccionada.
este es el código que me suma solo números y no horas
**Sub suma1()
  Dim uc As Integer, uf As Integer
  
  uc = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
  uf = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  'Cells(5, uc).Value = ""
  With Cells(5, uc).Resize(uf - 4)
    .Formula = "=SUM(B5:" & Cells(5, uc - 1).Address(5, 15) & ")"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
End Sub**

gracias de ante mano

Allí no veo el condicionante que dices de las 20:00 para restarle ni la suma si es 6:11 específicamente, aparte deberías para esto agregar un IF al recorrido.
Aquí el código agregando lo que te comente:
Sub suma1()
    Dim uc As Integer, uf As Integer
    Dim suma As Double
    Dim c As Range
    
    Dim celdaSuma As Range
    Set celdaSuma = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    
    suma = 0
    
    uc = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    uf = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(5, uc), Cells(uf, uc))
        If TimeValue(c.Value) < TimeValue("20:00") Then
            suma = suma + (TimeValue("20:00") - TimeValue(c.Value))
        ElseIf TimeValue(c.Value) >= TimeValue("06:11") Then
            suma = suma + TimeValue(c.Value)
        End If
    Next c
    
    celdaSuma.Value = suma
End Sub

